# Does increasing number of cores speed up execution time of a program where threads currently have 50% IO contention?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, io

Would I gain anything by adding more cores to a program that spends 50% waiting on IO? I get the trivial cases of completely IO bound and CPU bound, but I’m not totally sure on a scenario where each thread spends part of the time waiting on IO.

My intuition is that by adding cores, each thread now has more contention for IO. So now each thread may now spend ~60% of its time waiting for IO. So the result is a net neutral or even net negative.

**EDIT**
[Threads: Fast IO - Slow CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEwox.png)
[Threads: Balanced IO and CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRegu.png)

These are some example diagrams of simple situations where I am trying to understand how adding threads/cores affects IO wait time.

One interesting thing I see is that the ratio between task IO time and task CPU determines helpfulness of additional threads. For instance, if IO = 10ms and CPU = 40ms, then total task time = 50ms. 50ms/10ms = 5, so this situation could benefit from 5 threads but anymore may not improve performance.

Is this correct?

Comment: Well, sure.  If the program has one thread spending 50% on I/O then adding another can make it twice as fast.  The IO wait time of one will overlap with the compute time of the other.  Adding a 3rd thread does not make it faster.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm a little confused. What if I had 10 threads/cores running and they all spent 50% of their time waiting on IO? Would doubling threads/cores to 20 mean that execution time would cut in half, but further cores would be unhelpful?

Comment: Then the proper conclusion to draw is that there's a bug in the benchmark or somebody is trying to complete his homework assignment.  You'll have to think for yourself, the point of doing homework.

Comment: @HansPassant - That comment is unnecessary. I am not doing homework, I am trying to understand something. I am new to concurrency and turn to places like stackoverflow for help. I have done benchmarking to test this out, but I am still trying to understand the underlying mechanisms to make my understanding more complete.

Comment: I was quite explicit, if this is not homework then the benchmark is broken.  So show us the benchmark code if you want help.  Anything else is just a complete waste of everybody's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. How do you define "I/O contention"? If by that you mean that the current threads are all attempting to use a shared I/O device/medium and they are having to "get in line and wait" to use it, then: Yes, you should expect that adding *more* threads into the same queue, it will increase percentage of time spent waiting.

Look at it this way. What if the shared I/O were extremely predictable. Every time you make an I/O request on the shared medium, it takes say 10milliseconds. Then you will make a maximum of 100 I/O requests per second across all threads. If you have 10 threads, then, each thread gets to make 10 requests per second on average. Scaling the CPU to that, let's also assume its CPU usage is oriented around the requests. That is, assume it takes 50ms to do the calculations that will be stored for each I/O request. You are now then spending 50% of your time in "I/O contention". Out of every second then you get 10 cycles of [prepare a request (50ms) + do the I/O (50ms)].

Now, if you increase your 10 threads to 20, you now have twice as many threads trying to use the same limited 100-requests-per-second resource. Now each thread only gets to make 5 requests per second on average. That means it is spending 250ms of each second (5 x 50ms) in CPU time preparing requests and 750ms waiting in the I/O queue. So by doubling the thread count, you're now spending 75% of your per-thread time in contention on the shared resource.

Adding threads would continue to increase your I/O contention -- there's always some thread making progress, so it never quite gets to 100% (on average) but you could get close. If you have 100 threads, then each gets to complete only a single request every second (so, 50ms CPU + 950 milliseconds waiting = 95% contention). If you have a thousand threads/cores, now only 1 in 10 gets to complete a request each second (99.5% contention, each thread works for 50ms, then waits for 9.95 seconds for its turn at I/O).

Comment: This makes sense, thanks. I actually edited my question and added a diagram of what you're describing (with slightly different numbers). I think I confused myself by thinking that more thread contention = worse performance. If I am understanding things correctly, adding threads is helpful even if the individual threads have more contention as long as collectively more processing is happening. Eventually, adding more threads won't be helpful though if I understand things correctly.

Comment: Yeah. I'd say it depends on exactly what your threads are doing. If the I/O being performed *is* the end result that you're trying to achieve (as in my thought experiment) then, once the I/O resource is being kept "saturated", there's little point in adding new threads.

Comment: There are also differences in the behavior of I/O. For example, if you're doing I/O writes [say, to a hard disk] on a modern OS, then typically those are near instantaneous (at least *until some queue fills*) - i.e. the OS will say "yes that's done" even though the I/O is actually just queued. An I/O read, on the other hand, will tend to be serial/synchronous: you usually can't continue until it's finished.